# Campo preenchido com data de hoje na inicialização da view

Tags: angular

Ola,

Queria colocar a data de hoje pre definida em um campo de data na inicialização da view.

Eu tentei assim:

Component:

```
this.MeuForm = this.fb.group({
  dataInicio: [{date: {year: (new Date()).getFullYear(), month: (new Date()).getMonth() + 1, day: (new Date()).getDate()}}],
  dataFim: ''
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="dataInicio">Data Inicial</label>
      <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          formControlName="dataInicio"></dx-date-box>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="dataFim">Data Final</label>
      <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          formControlName="dataFim"></dx-date-box>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que, primeiro, não aparece a data de hoje e segundo, eu nao tenho mais o icone ali para escolher outra data.

Comment: tenta dataFim: new Date(), da uma olhada na documentação dessa sua biblioteca que tipo de dados ele espera.

Comment: funcionou, obrigado